# Recreating ubuntu mirror structure on local mirror using aptly

Tags: apt, apt-mirror

I am currently trying to mirror the ubuntu-cloud repos to a local mirror but I am unable to recreate their structure.

I have been using the following commands to create the local apt repo using aptly:

## create mirrors:

```
aptly mirror create ubuntu-cloud-liberty http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/liberty main
aptly mirror create ubuntu-cloud-mitaka http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/mitaka main
```

## update mirrors

```
aptly mirror update ubuntu-cloud-liberty
aptly mirror update ubuntu-cloud-mitaka
```

## create snapshots

```
aptly snapshot create ubuntu-cloud-liberty-current from mirror ubuntu-cloud-liberty
aptly snapshot create ubuntu-cloud-mitaka-current from mirror ubuntu-cloud-mitaka
```

## publishing the snapshots

```
aptly publish snapshot -component=liberty,mitaka -distribution=trusty-updates ubuntu-cloud-liberty-current ubuntu-cloud-mitaka-current ubuntu
```

This generates the following structure to the binary-i386 Packages file:

**/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/liberty/binary-i386/Packages**

Whereas the structure on the ubuntu repos is:

**/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/liberty/main/binary-i386/Packages**

That is, I can't get a 'main' directory created under the component directories.

Would anyone be able to suggest how I can publish the snapshots (or create the mirrors) so that the structure is maintained.

`/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/liberty/binary-i386/Packages

Whereas the structure on the ubuntu repos is:

/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/liberty/main/binary-i386/Packages`

That is, I can't get a 'main' directory created under the component directories.

Would anyone be able to suggest how I can publish the snapshots (or create the mirrors) so that the structure is maintained.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, but you could try fudging things like this, see if it sticks and call it a day.

```
cd /ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/liberty
ln -s . main
```